# Filtering data-frame columns using regex, then using .groupby to calculate sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I want to group, filter columns by regex, and then sum.

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                   'Invasive' : [12,1,1,0,1,0], 
                   'invasive': [1,4,5,3,4,6],
                   'Wild':[4,7,1,0,0,0],
                   'wild':[0,0,9,8,3,2],
                   'Crop':[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'Crop_2':[2,3,2,2,1,2]})

df.groupby(['ID']).filter(regex='(Invasive)|(invasive)|(Wild)|(wild)').sum()
```

The error message I get is:

`DataFrameGroupBy.filter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

I get the same Err message if `groupby` comes after `filter`

Why does this happen? Where do I input the `func` argument?

EDIT:

My Expected output is one column that has summed across the filtered columns and is grouped by ID. E.g.:

```
   ID  Output
0   1      29
1   2      27
2   3      16
```

Comment: what you want to do doesn't make sense, `groupby.filter` is to filter **rows**, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do doesn't make sense, [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) is to filter **rows**, not to be confused with [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

You likely want to filter the columns, then to aggregate:

```
df.filter(regex='(?i)(Invasive|Wild)').groupby(df['ID']).sum()
```

*NB. I replaced `(Invasive)|(invasive)|(Wild)|(wild)` by `(?i)(Invasive|Wild)`, which means 'Invasive`OR`Wild` independently of the case.*

Output:

```
    Invasive  invasive  Wild  wild
ID                                
1         13         5    11     0
2          1         8     1    17
3          1        10     0     5
```

##### edit:

the output that you show needs a further summation per row:

```
out = (df.filter(regex='(?i)(Invasive|Wild)')
         .groupby(df['ID']).sum()
         .sum(axis=1)
         .reset_index(name='Output')
      )

# or with summation before:
out = (df.filter(regex='(?i)(Invasive|Wild)')
         .sum(axis=1)
         .groupby(df['ID']).sum()
         .reset_index(name='Output')
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID  Output
0   1      29
1   2      27
2   3      16
```